# What is wrong in this java code. It says "Terminated Application" in Eclipse

Tags: java, if-statement

```
package javagain;

public class Gender_interest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        if((args[0] == "Female") && (Integer.parseInt(args[1])>=1) && (Integer.parseInt(args[1])<=58)) {
            System.out.println("Percentge of Interest is 8.2%");
        }

        else if((args[0] == "Male") && (Integer.parseInt(args[1])>=1) && (Integer.parseInt(args[1])<=58)) {
            System.out.println("Percentge of Interest is 8.4%");
        }

        else if((args[0] == "Female") && (Integer.parseInt(args[1])>=59) && (Integer.parseInt(args[1])<=100)) {
            System.out.println("Percentge of Interest is 9.2%");
        }

        else if((args[0] == "Male") && (Integer.parseInt(args[1])>=59) && (Integer.parseInt(args[1])<=100)) {
            System.out.println("Percentge of Interest is 10.5%");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Enter correct values.");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Essentially, *Terminated Application* indicates that the execution of the program is complete and the Java Virtual Machine has exited. It will appear even if your program exits with no error so it doesn't necessarily mean that something has gone wrong. PS: It seems that you need to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) in order to have a better understanding on how you should compare Strings in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here **(args[0] == "Female")** is wrong , in java == checks the memory location  of the String (objects) where these will be saved. You should use **(args[0].equals("Female")) or (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Female"))**